# How To Validate The Phone Number with one character only

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to make validate phone number with one character only.
here is the example: XXX-XXXXXXX 
i just want to put "-" only. 
here is my coding function.

```
function val()
{ 
    if(addform.staff_mobile_phone.value=="")
    {
        alert("Please enter the phone number");
        addform.staff_mobile_phone.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(isNaN(addform.staff_mobile_phone.value))
    {
        alert("Invalid Phone Number");
        addform.staff_mobile_phone.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if((addform.staff_mobile_phone.value).length<10)
    {
        alert ("Phone number should be minimum 10 digits");
        addform.staff_mobile_phone.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

if had something wrong with this code, please help me. I really need your help.

Comment: phone number with one character only?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using a regular expression for validation?

Comment: You [can use these](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=phone) regular expressions if you are willing to..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the exact format you need, but it might look like:

```
/\d{3}-\d{7,}/.test("123-4567890")
```

Above regular expression would match any phone number consisting of three digits, followed by a hyphen (`-`) and then followed by at least seven more digits.

If the hyphen is not mandatory, you could use (note the question mark):

```
/\d{3}-?\d{7,}/.test("1234567890")
```

And if you want to limit the total number of digits to, say, 12 (so three digits followed by a hyphen and then followed by 7-9 more digits) you would use:

```
/\d{3}-\d{7,9}/.test("123-456789012")
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean you want to validate a number avoiding some char separator in it, so why making it work just for char '-' ?

```
function normalizeInput(inputString) {
    var vectorSeparatori = new Array();
    vectorSeparatori[0] = ' ';
    vectorSeparatori[1] = '-';
    vectorSeparatori[1] = '/';
    //Remove also spaces
    inputString= trim(inputString);
    //
    for (var i = 0; i < vectorSeparatori.length;i++) {
        inputString = inputString.split(vectorSeparatori[i]).join('');
    }

    return inputString ;
}
```

Just preprocess the whole input value with a normalization function (like the one above). If you want to add more separators just add 'em to the vectorSeparatori array, then perform your validation on the number. For phone numbers there's not a 100% fail save validation (probably my Italian phone number won't pass some regexp validations I've seen around), so I  think it's better getting rid off the extra chars and then do just a light client side validation, delegating to a server side check a more strict one.